# How can I get usage data from my Skype account?

Tags: skype-for-web, statistics

I would like to get details of calls, like exact date, time consumption and bandwidth.

Is it possible in Skype?

Comment: You have tagged this as `skype-for-web`, but are you actually accessing it through the web interface?

Comment: @jonsca : I think a feature like this could be accessible via the web interface.